# Function to generate a retry with time accumulator every error

Tags: python

I have a main file that calls the secondary:

```
import code_two

if __name__ == '__main__':
    code_two.main()
```

file `code_two.py`:

```
from random import randint
import time

def try_again(a):
    print(a)
    while True:
        sleep_time += 30
        print('Next attempt in: '+ str(sleep_time/60) + ' minute(s)')
        sleep(sleep_time)
        main(sleep_time=sleep_time)
        return

def main(sleep_time=0):
    try:
        value = randint(0,1)
        if value == 0:
            1/0
    except Exception as e:
        try_again(e)

    try:
        value = randint(2,3)
        if value == 2:
            1/0
    except Exception as e:
        try_again(e)

    try:
        value = randint(4,5)
        if value == 4:
            1/0
    except Exception as e:
        try_again(e)
```

The error when trying to call the function to retry after an error in the `main()` function is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sleep_time' referenced before assignment
```

Since there are three `try except` and an error can occur in any of the three, I'm trying to make a separate function so the code doesn't get so repetitive and I just need to use `try_again(e)` instead of all the rest of the code.

Just to clarify, if there is an error, he needs to wait 30 seconds to try again and if there is an error in the new attempt, then he will need to wait 60 seconds (30 from the previous attempt + 30 from the new attempt)

Comment: You said `sleep_time += 30`. It needs to be defined before. Also, why are you dividing by zero to try to raise an exception? You should do it explicitly, eg `raise RuntimeError()`, or avoid using exceptions like this and just put the `try_again` inside of the if block. Also: `main` and `try_again` call each other (one in a loop even!) and you will get into an infinite call loop that will eventually stack overflow. You passed `sleep_time` to `main()` but never used it.

Comment: Don't use (mutual) recursion to  implement a loop.

Comment: Hi @EricJin I'm generating this ```1/0``` to shorten the code sent to the question here from stackoverflow, because the actual code is too big, I took anything that threw an error just to speed up the sample.

Comment: Hi @chepner could you help me understand how I can generate this loop correctly given that there are three places in the code that can generate an error and need to be retried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your loop to `main`, and pass the sleep time to `try_again` as an argument.

```
from random import randint
import time


def try_again(a, s):
    print(a)
    print('Next attempt in: '+ str(s/60) + ' minute(s)')
    sleep(s)
    return s + 30


def main(sleep_time=0):
    done = False
    while not done:
        try:
            value = randint(0,1)
            if value == 0:
                1/0
        except Exception as e:
            sleep_time = try_again(e, sleep_time)
            continue
    
        try:
            value = randint(2,3)
            if value == 2:
                1/0
        except Exception as e:
            sleep_time = try_again(e, sleep_time)
            continue
    
        try:
            value = randint(4,5)
            if value == 4:
                1/0
        except Exception as e:
            sleep_time = try_again(e, sleep_time)
            continue

        done = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The  `+=` operator does not instantiate the object, it assigns a new value to an already created object. Therefore, in the scope of the function `try_again()`, the interpreter tries to find the variable `sleep_time` to assign a new value before it has been created.

Comment: Yes, I understand, how can I proceed so that I can create this function separately without having to repeat so much code? Is there any way?